# execute goal mvn-failsafe-plugin: (failsafe-integration-tests) project x: suiteXmlFiles is configured, but there is no TestNG dependency

Tags: java, maven

i am using maven failsafe plugin to execute the integration test cases along with cobertura plugin. 
in the configuration of failsafe plugin, i have given suiteXmlFile which has all the integration tests 
however, when run the following command , i am getting error 
command is : mvn cobertura:cobertura-integration -DskipITs=false
and error is :

Failed to execute goal maven-failsafe-plugin:2.17:integration-test (failsafe-integration-tests) on project xx: suiteXmlFiles is configured, but there is no TestNG dependency

here is the snippet from pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.17</version>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>/home/adam/coberturaint/reporting/src/test/resources/testng/it-test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
          <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
          <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</plugin>
```

i am using fail-safe plugin version : 2.17

i have mentioned the dependency of testng everywhere, but still i am getting dependency error 
please suggest

regards

Comment: please suggest. i am stuck

Answer (score 1):

You need to go a different way cause the messages it already.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.8</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.17</version>
          <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
              <suiteXmlFile>/home/adam/coberturaint/reporting/src/test/resources/testng/it-test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

Apart from that you need to call maven like this:

```
mvn verify
```

to run the integration-test phase. If you call Maven like this:

```
mvn cobertura:cobertura-integration
```

You have no life cycle which will not run the integration tests.

You should prevent using absolute paths in your pom file as you do with your suite file. The question is on the other hand why you need a suite file. In TestNG usually you don't need one.

Comment: i need code coverage also so because of that i am executing mvn cobertura:cobertura-integration . if i just run mvn verify , then only integration test cases will be executed , but then what about code coverage .. how i will get that

Comment: You have to integrate cobertura in the build life cycle as well.

Comment: can you please give me some example on how to do that ?

Comment: i guess i have integrated cobertura in the build life cycle . however, now i am getting sometimes class not found error OR dependency isssue

Comment: please help. i am really stuck